# Dynamic resize of an AS3 Shape, best code?

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, resize, shapes

I'm currently looking for advice on the best practice for Drawing a fluid rounded rectangle in **AS3**. I've used Flash for quite some time but am now seeking to refine how I use it and there a few things which seems overly complex for what is being done.

I have a work area Screen which is **1000**px x **500**px.

I set a **10**px x **10**px border gap for my Shape, set it up as below so it has rounded edges, **25** pixels.

Everything works fine, I can resize the screen and it always allows a **10** x **10** pixel border and keeps the **25** pixel rounded edge, it just seems having all the code for the resize is excessive? Is there a better way I'm unaware of?

```
//Declare my Shape. 
public var my_shape : Shape = new Shape();

//In code call function to drawShape
drawBackgroundShape();

//I detect for screen resize.
stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, resizeBackground );

public function drawBackgroundShape(): void {
    my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xCCCCCC, 1);
    my_shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,1); 
    my_shape.graphics.drawRoundRect(10, 10, 980, 480, 25);
    my_shape.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(my_shape);
}

private function resizeBackground ( event:Event ):void {
    my_shape.graphics.clear();
    my_shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xCCCCCC, 1);
    my_shape.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,1); 
    my_shape.graphics.drawRoundRect(10, 10, stage.stageWidth - 20, stage.stageHeight - 20, 25);
    my_shape.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Is this the most efficient way to change the size of the Shape being drawn?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may set `my_shape.scaleX` and `my_shape.scaleY`.

Comment: @HITMAN - Thanks, if I scale it, it deforms the corner radius accordingly, to keep the edges and radius square the redraw seems to work best it just seems code heavy to resize it. If it were square edged then as you suggested would be fine I'm sure.

Comment: 9-Slice-Scaling should work here, afaik. Here's a [documentation link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7df3.html). (Refer to the _Controlling distortion when scaling_ section)

Comment: yes it's fine to do it like that.

Comment: @DodgerThud - Thanks. I tried. However if you scale down really small (unlikely I know), it has issues dealing with the margin size. This is the same with any screen below 70x70 pixels means it has to conflict with it's restrictions.ie (10 + 25 * 2) height /width.

It's unlikely that it would be used this way but I favour the coded option to keep file size down.

Comment: @BotMaster - Thanks. It works fine just having to redraw the whole segment of code in the resize seemed like a misuse of code, but if it's right, great.

Comment: @esadude. At first, I didn't understand that you want to keep that `25`. So, your code is the best possible one.

Comment: I usually recommend to use the RENDER event for redraw operations to avoid redundant drawing but I don't think this is needed when used with a RESIZE event.

Comment: Thanks for all your input guys, much appreciated. Everyday's a school day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't great, because

1. there's a bunch of duplicated code
2. there are some magic numbers that aren't really necessary
3. it's not encapsulated very  well

You solve problem 3. by creating a class for the border. 1. is solved by having the code that draws the border only once. And finally 2. is solved by reusing that code even for the initialisation.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class BackgroundShape extends Shape
    {
        private var margin:Number;
        private var fillColor:uint;
        private var lineColor:uint;   

        public function BackgroundShape(margin:Number = 10, lineColor:uint = 0xCCCCCC, fillColor:uint = 0xFFFFFF)
        {
            this.margin = margin;
            this.lineColor = lineColor;
            this.fillColor = fillColor;

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        }

        private function onStage(event:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, drawBackground);

            drawBackground();
        }

        private function drawBackground(event:Event = null):void 
        {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle(1, lineColor, 1);
            graphics.beginFill(fillColor,1); 
            graphics.drawRoundRect(margin, margin, stage.stageWidth - 2 * margin, stage.stageHeight - 2 * margin, 25);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to use the class like any other DisplayObject. It does not have to be treated differently, by calling some initialising function in order to add it to the screen. There are no hard coded magic numbers that have to be adopted for other screen sizes:

```
var bg:BackgroundShape = new BackgroundShape();
addChild(bg);
```

Comment: Thanks @Null - Much appreciated, I made it a multiuse class and tweaked the margin settings so it suited the project, but that was more what I had in mind for the coding. Much more intuitive, thanks again!